# How can I compute the probability of committing a type 2 error?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, error, type-i-and-ii-errors

> Let $X_1,...X_n$ be an iid sample distributed as $\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$. We have the following tests $$H_0: \mu=0~~~\text{vs.}~~~H_1:\mu\neq 0$$and we use the statistic $T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ and the test function $$\delta=\Bbb{1}_{|T|\geq Q}$$ for some $Q>0$. I want to find the probability of committing a type 2 error, ie compute $\Bbb{P}_\mu(\delta=0)$

Let observe that $T\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, 1/n)$ therefore we define a random variable $Z$ s.t. $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, 1/n)$.

$$\begin{align}\Bbb{P}_\mu(\delta=0)&=\Bbb{P}_\mu(T<Q)+ \Bbb{P}_\mu(T>-Q)\\&=\Bbb{P}(Z<Q)+\Bbb{P}(Z>-Q)\\&=\Bbb{P}\left(\sqrt{n}(Z-\mu)<\sqrt{n}(Q-\mu)\right)+\Bbb{P}\left(\sqrt{n}(Z-\mu)>\sqrt{n}(-Q-\mu)\right)\\&=\Phi\left(\sqrt{n}(Q-\mu)\right)+1-\Bbb{P}\left(\sqrt{n}(Z-\mu)\leq\sqrt{n}(-Q-\mu)\right)\\&=\Phi\left(\sqrt{n}(Q-\mu)\right)+1-\Phi\left(-\sqrt{n}(Q+\mu)\right)\\&=\Phi\left(\sqrt{n}(Q-\mu)\right)+\Phi\left(\sqrt{n}(Q+\mu)\right)\end{align}$$

where we used that $\sqrt(n)(Z-\mu)\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable. I also used that $\Phi(-z)=1-\Phi(z)$. But I don't think that this is correct since in class our prof. told us that the solution is $\Phi\left(\sqrt{n}(Q-\mu)\right)-\Phi\left(\sqrt{n}(-Q-\mu)\right)$.

Can someone tell me where my error is?

Comment: What is your justification for $\Bbb{P}_\mu(\delta=0)=\Bbb{P}_\mu(T<Q)+ \Bbb{P}_\mu(T>-Q)$ rather than $=\Bbb{P}_\mu(-Q <T<Q)=\Bbb{P}_\mu(T<Q)- \Bbb{P}_\mu(T\le -Q)$?

Comment: @Henry hmm maybe here is my mistake. I somehow didn't thought about it, because in the exercise before we also have $\Bbb{P}(|T|\geq Q)=\Bbb{P}(T\leq -Q)+\Bbb{P}(T\geq Q)$ so I did it in the same way. Why does it then work in one but not the other case?

Comment: So $\Bbb{P}(|T|\lt Q) $ $=1-\Bbb{P}(|T|\geq Q)$ $=1-\Bbb{P}(T\leq -Q)-\Bbb{P}(T\geq Q) $ $= \Bbb{P}(T\lt Q)-\Bbb{P}(T\leq -Q)$ remembering that that you can add probabilities of disjoint events but not of intersecting events

Comment: @Henry sorry I'm still confused why wouln't I then have $\Bbb{P}(|T|\geq Q)=\Bbb{P}(T\leq -Q)-\Bbb{P}(T\geq Q)$ when I do it as in your first comment?

Comment: Subtraction of probability only works when one event is a subset of another event: for example $(T\leq -Q) \subset (T\lt Q)$ assuming $Q$ is positive but  $(T\ge Q) \not\subset (T\le -Q)$

Comment: @Henry Hmm, but is it true that $\Bbb{P}(|T|\geq Q)=\Bbb{P}(Q\leq T\leq -Q)$?

Comment: No. $\Bbb{P}(|T|\leq Q)=\Bbb{P}(Q\leq T\leq -Q)$ and $\Bbb{P}(|T|\geq Q)=1-\Bbb{P}(Q\lt T\lt -Q)$

Comment: I do not do chat

Comment: @Henry But I mean $\Bbb{P}(|T|\geq Q)=\Bbb{P}(T\geq Q, T\leq -Q)$?

Comment: Whait I think you look at the wrong inequality. I want $|T|\geq Q$ then this is equivalent to say $T\geq Q$ and $-T\geq Q \Leftrightarrow T\leq -Q$?

Comment: $\Bbb{P}(T\geq Q, T\leq -Q)=\Bbb{P}((T\geq Q) \cap (T\leq -Q))=0$.  You want $\Bbb{P}(|T|\geq Q)=\Bbb{P}((T\geq Q) \cup (T\leq -Q))$ so "or" not "and"

Comment: @Henry ah and since $\{T\geq Q\}$ and $\{T\leq -Q\}$ are disjoint we can add the probablities. But now if I want $\Bbb{P}_\mu(|T|<Q)=\Bbb{P}(\{T<Q\}\cap\{T>-Q\})$ why do I have an intersection here and not a union as above

Comment: Intersections are shown by $\cap$

Comment: @Henry Yes but why is it an intersection? I mean I initially wanted to write $\Bbb{P}_\mu(|T|<Q)=\Bbb{P}(\{T<Q\}\cup\{T>-Q\})$ As in the case above but why is this wrong I dont see it

Comment: If you took $\{T<Q\}\cup\{T>-Q\}$ you would have all possible values of $T$ so a probability of $1$

Comment: @Henry sure but I mean why is $|T|\geq Q$ and $|T|<Q$ such a difference? I don't see it here I think here is the confusion because in $|T|\geq Q$ you take a union and in the case $|T|<Q$ an intersection and I don't see why there is this difference there are only different signs

Comment: Consider the intervals: $\{|T|\geq Q\}=(-\infty,-Q] \cup [Q,\infty)$ while  $\{|T|\lt Q\}=(-Q,Q)$ $=(-\infty,Q) \cap (-Q,\infty)$ $=(-\infty,Q)\backslash (-\infty,-Q]$

Comment: @Henry aah stupid  I see thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your  $$\Bbb{P}_\mu(\delta=0)=\Bbb{P}_\mu(T<Q)+ \Bbb{P}_\mu(T>-Q)$$

should be $$\Bbb{P}_\mu(\delta=0)=\Bbb{P}_\mu(-Q <T<Q)=\Bbb{P}_\mu(T<Q)- \Bbb{P}_\mu(T\le -Q)$$

Comment: But is it then true that for example $\Bbb{P}(|T|\leq Q)=\Bbb{P}(-Q\leq T\leq Q)=\Bbb{P}(T\leq Q)-\Bbb{P}(T<-Q)$

Comment: Yes indeed it is

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Comment: I have asked a question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618852/how-can-i-find-the-value-q-for-which-the-given-region-is-a-confidence-region-f would it be possible if you could take a look at it?